# Power mux LTC4412HV not doing what I expect

Tags: power

I have created the following circuit:

[image]

Following are the variables:

- VPOE: 12V supply
- VEXT: external supply between 10VDC and 34VDC
- VSWITCHED: any voltage between 10V and 36VDC that goes to the load.

My goal is that VPOE is always supplying all current to the load (VSWITCHED) in case it is present. As soon as VPOE is not present any more the load should be supplied by VEXT. This means:

- VPOE smaller than say 10VDC --> Go to VEXT
- VPOE larger than 10VDC --> Go to VPOE

From reading the datasheet I thought that whenever CTL is asserted high, the mosfet Q1 should switch off. This is not happening. The circuit only works when VPOE is about the same as VEXT, than VPOE is the only supply which feeds current to the load.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The transistor Q1 has an internal diode that will conduct Vext to Vswitched when forward biased. So if Vext is higher than Vpoe, Vext determines the voltage on Vswitched.

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast question. I'm not sure how this can be 'fixed' easily. Any suggestions?

Comment: Aha, I think I found the solution. I'm going to try and create a back to back solution by adding another MOSFET after Q1 with drain and source swapped

Comment: Yes, I would suggest going back to the datasheet and looking at Figure 4.

Comment: It is now fixed and working perfectly both in theory and practice. Thank you @AndrewLentvorski for helping out!